# Asking a riddle

Tags: discussion, advice

What is the general stance on riddles being asked on math.stackexchange.com?

My friends and I are debating a riddle but none of us are sure of what the correct way is to approach it.

If math.stackexchange.com isn't the place to post this, where then?

**EDIT**

The riddle:

> There are 100 soldiers. 85 lose a left leg, 80 lose a right leg, 75
>   lose a left arm, 70 lose a right arm. What is the minimum number of
>   soldiers losing all 4 limbs?

Comment: It depends on whether the riddle is sufficiently mathematical. You might as well post it in this meta question and see what people think.

Comment: @DylanMoreland I think the riddle would qualify as being mathematical enough. Please see edit.

Comment: This looks okay to me (as WW says, it's best if you post your own thoughts along with the question), if a little macabre!

Comment: I think that question is fine (I wouldn't really call it a riddle, even). You may want to elaborate, when you post, on how you and your friend reach your differing conclusions. Also, you probably should tag it (pigeonhole-principle) and/or (inclusion-exclusion)

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102598/100-soldiers-riddle

Comment: Also this question from meta is perhaps interesting here: [PUZZLING — Area 51 proposal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231/puzzling-area-51-proposal)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The purpose of the Math Stack Exchange is as a *Question and Answer* forum for *mathematics*.

So in regards to riddles, I think most users would agree with the following tests:

1. Is the *nature* of the riddle mathematical? A logic puzzle like [knight and knaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_and_Knaves) is, a clever word play on mathematical terminology ("What's yellow and implies the axiom of choice?") is not.
2. Do you already know the answer to the riddle? Math.SE is not a "riddle-me-this" forum, and we discourage the asking of a question (or in this case, a riddle) for the sake of "asking a question". (For example, if your motivation is that "this is a fun riddle and people should see it" or "I want to ask a riddle and judge whether people answered correctly" then perhaps this website is not the right forum.)
3. For logic puzzles, have you done your homework? A lot of logic puzzles have long-standing known solutions easily found on the internet. In some cases the solutions have been discussed on this site before.

In your case, a *poor way* to ask the question would be:

> Here's a riddle. What's the solution?

A *slightly better way* to ask the question would be:

> Here's a riddle. Starting from so-and-so we can deduce thus-and-thus that the answer must be such-and-such. But starting from this-and-that we can deduce here-and-there so the answer must be not-such-nor-such. Which is the right answer?

Though most likely in this case it is just that the hypothesis of the riddle contains two contradictory statements.

---

BTW, since you already asked this question, Dylan's comment is very practical. But in general there is no need to really *vet* your question before posting it. Just remember that

- A question being closed does not reflect poorly on you as a person; unless of course you refuse to learn from the experience and keep posting similar questions over and over again (which, by the way, would be considered spamming).
- A question being closed does not necessarily reflect that the question, in the abstract, is a bad question: it may just be that the community deems the question unsuitable for this particular forum. (In other words: it's not you, it's us.)

If you can keep that in mind, there's usually no harm to just asking the question on the main site.

Comment: Zorn's lemon? I actually prefer "What can carry you in the Andes and implies the axiom of choice?".

Comment: @Asaf: or "what do you call a Tibetan monk enslaved by Magneto in disguise, who also implies the axiom of choice?" The lemon version is shorter and sweeter.

Comment: "We discourage the asking of a question (or in this case, a riddle) when you already know the answer."  That is not universal.  E.g. asking and answering one's own question is sometimes encouraged, or asking to learn of other ways of answering.  I think as long as the question makes the intent clear (and the question is on topic), this usually works.  Maybe it applies in the case of a riddle where there is a unique trick to getting the riddle, but if it is mathematical rather than word play that seems unlikely to happen.

Comment: @Jonas: I see I didn't make it clear. Let me try to re-write that sentence.

Comment: @Jonas: BTW, if the "question" is "how can one solve this problem differently", I would say that the OP does _not_ know the answer already. Like you said, the point of the second bullet is one of intent.

Comment: @Willie: Thank you for clarifying.  I agree.

Comment: Something related to @Jonas's comment: In a few cases, the poster has an idea of how to solve the problem and just wants a confirmation that the proof is correct/rigorous etc. This is also usually considered on-topic. [Of course, as Willie points out, here again the "question" is "Is my work correct?" and not "Give me a proof/hint", so the OP does not know the answer already.]

Comment: @Srivatsan: I agree. I think "is my work correct" is perfectly on-topic. At least until MSE grows large enough to warrant our own [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) like spin-off :p (in which case it may be only off-topic by virtue of having a better site for the question; but let us not get ahead of ourselves here). On the other hand, I don't really know how to answer those questions. I mean, we can't really just post the one word "Yes"...

Comment: Willie: Hm, ProofReview.SE is an amusing thought to me right now :-), but yes, it might become necessary and useful in the future.

Comment: Willie, it's the lemon *flower* that is sweet. The fruit of the poor lemon is impossible to eat. Will Holt had nothing to say with regard to the lemon version. http://www.mudcat.org/@displaysong.cfm?SongID=3546

Comment: @Gerry: have you actually _tasted_ llama? (BTW, nor have I...) I certainly did not claim lemon is a maximal element in terms of sweetness. I only claim that it is not a minimal element. `;p`